# Converting a struct to a bson document

Tags: mongodb, go, struct, mongo-go

I have a struct that looks like this:

```
type User struct {
    UserID              string `bson:"user_id"`
    Name            string `bson:"name"`
    Address         string `bson:"address"`
}
```

I am using mongo's `UpdateOne` to only update specific fields in a document. Doing this allows me to only update the name where the `user_id` is 1234:

```
filter := bson.D{{"user_id", "1234"}}
update := bson.D{{"$set",
        bson.D{
            {"name", "john"},
        },
    }}
myCollection.UpdateOne(context.Background(), filter, update)
```

However, I want to use a struct instead to replace whatever is in the `update` variable.
So I want to be able use,

```
update:= User{Name: "john"}
```

How do I convert this to a `bson` document like in the working example?

Answer (score 4):

Most responses always use **bson.Marshal()** followed by **bson.Unmarshal()**, but this form is slower.

Imagine that you are on a server with thousands of accesses to the database per second. Your code can slow down server operation depending on the quality of the code.
For this reason, I always do the benchmark tests before choosing which method to use.

An example is shown below:

```
    package bsontest
    
    import (
        "errors"
        "fmt"
        "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
        "reflect"
        "testing"
    )
    
    type User struct {
        UniqueID    string    `bson:"_id"`
        Name        string    `bson:"name"`
        Password    string    `bson:"password"`
        Email       string    `bson:"email"`
        Age         int       `bson:"age"`
        Admin       bool      `bson:"admin"`
    }
    
    func (e *User) FromBson(data bson.M) (err error) {
        var tagValue string
    
        element := reflect.ValueOf(e).Elem()
    
        for i := 0; i < element.NumField(); i += 1 {
            typeField := element.Type().Field(i)
            tag := typeField.Tag
    
            tagValue = tag.Get("bson")
    
            if tagValue == "-" {
                continue
            }
    
            switch element.Field(i).Kind() {
            case reflect.String:
                switch data[tagValue].(type) {
                case string:
                    element.Field(i).SetString(data[tagValue].(string))
    
                default:
                    err = errors.New(tagValue+" must be a string")
                    return
                }
    
            case reflect.Bool:
                switch data[tagValue].(type) {
                case bool:
                    element.Field(i).SetBool(data[tagValue].(bool))
    
                default:
                    err = errors.New(tagValue+" must be a boolean")
                    return
                }
    
            case reflect.Int:
                switch data[tagValue].(type) {
                case int:
                    element.Field(i).SetInt(int64(data[tagValue].(int)))
                case int64:
                    element.Field(i).SetInt(data[tagValue].(int64))
                default:
                    err = errors.New(tagValue+" must be a integer")
                    return
                }
            }
        }
    
        return
    }
    
    func (e *User) ToBson() (data bson.M) {
        var tagValue string
    
        data = bson.M{}
        element := reflect.ValueOf(e).Elem()
    
        for i := 0; i < element.NumField(); i += 1 {
            typeField := element.Type().Field(i)
            tag := typeField.Tag
    
            tagValue = tag.Get("bson")
    
            if tagValue == "-" {
                continue
            }
    
            switch element.Field(i).Kind() {
            case reflect.String:
                value := element.Field(i).String()
                data[tagValue] = value
    
            case reflect.Bool:
                value := element.Field(i).Bool()
                data[tagValue] = value
    
            case reflect.Int:
                value := element.Field(i).Int()
                data[tagValue] = value
            }
        }
    
        return
    }
    
    var user User
    
    func init() {
        user = User{
            UniqueID: "12345-67890-ABCDE-FGHIJKL",
            Name:     "Fulano da Silva Sauro",
            Password: "pangea",
            Email:    "sauro@pangea.com",
            Admin:    true,
        }
    }
    
    func ExampleUser_ToBson() {
        var err error
        var userAsBSon = user.ToBson()
        fmt.Printf("%+v\n", userAsBSon)
    
        user = User{}
        fmt.Printf("%+v\n", user)
    
        err = user.FromBson(userAsBSon)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    
        fmt.Printf("%+v\n", user)
    
        // Output:
        // map[_id:12345-67890-ABCDE-FGHIJKL admin:true age:0 email:sauro@pangea.com name:Fulano da Silva Sauro password:pangea]
        // {UniqueID: Name: Password: Email: Age:0 Admin:false}
        // {UniqueID:12345-67890-ABCDE-FGHIJKL Name:Fulano da Silva Sauro Password:pangea Email:sauro@pangea.com Age:0 Admin:true}
    }
    
    func Benchmark_UsingMarshalAndUnmarshal(b *testing.B) {
        var err error
        var bsonAsByte []byte
        var bsonData bson.M
    
        for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
            bsonAsByte, err = bson.Marshal(&user)
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
            err = bson.Unmarshal(bsonAsByte, &bsonData)
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func Benchmark_UsingUnmarshalAndMarshal(b *testing.B) {
        var err error
        var bsonAsByte []byte
        var bsonData = bson.M{
            "_id":"12345-67890-ABCDE-FGHIJKL",
            "admin":true,
            "age":0,
            "email":"sauro@pangea.com",
            "name":"Fulano da Silva Sauro",
            "password":"pangea",
        }
    
        for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
            bsonAsByte, err = bson.Marshal(&bsonData)
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
            err = bson.Unmarshal(bsonAsByte, &user)
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func Benchmark_UsingToBson(b *testing.B) {
        var err error
        var bsonData = bson.M{
            "_id":"12345-67890-ABCDE-FGHIJKL",
            "admin":true,
            "age":0,
            "email":"sauro@pangea.com",
            "name":"Fulano da Silva Sauro",
            "password":"pangea",
        }
    
        for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
            err = user.FromBson(bsonData)
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func Benchmark_UsingFromBson(b *testing.B) {
        var bsonData bson.M
    
        for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
            bsonData = user.ToBson()
        }
    
        _ = bsonData
    }
```

Times:

```
Benchmark_UsingMarshalAndUnmarshal
Benchmark_UsingMarshalAndUnmarshal-8      398800          2996 ns/op

Benchmark_UsingToBson
Benchmark_UsingToBson-8                   1789176          643.0 ns/op

Benchmark_UsingFromBson
Benchmark_UsingFromBson-8                 2128242          539.6 ns/op

Benchmark_UsingUnmarshalAndMarshal
Benchmark_UsingUnmarshalAndMarshal-8      474501          2524 ns/op
```